# How to rewite pandas to sql with drop_duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql

I have the following code in pandas

```
pand = tb.sort_values(['created_at','id','name'], ascending = False).drop_duplicates(['id','name','day'])
```

So I rewrote it like this in SQL. However, the results of these two codes are different, can't get why.

````
(SELECT *, 
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            Partition by id,name,day
            ORDER BY 
                created_at DESC,id DESC,name DESC

    ) as row_num
into  new
     FROM tb);
DELETE FROM  new
WHERE row_num > 1;
```
````

Comment: That is not valid TSql so it will not work in SQL Server. You have tagged multiple database engines and any solution will likely depend on the engine and its SQL dialect. And for future reference, "are different, can't get why" are not useful things to write. How is the result different? Show an example.

Comment: @SMor I working with Postgresql.Sorry, can't show any examples, as when I try ths code out on dummy data everything works just fine, however,when I apply it to real data, the outcome differs. I thought, maybe someone will see mistake in the script

Answer (score 1):

In case you can afford `DROP TABLE` use an intermediate table:

```
CREATE TABLE tb_temp (LIKE tb);

INSERT INTO tb_temp
SELECT DISTINCT ON (id,name,day) * FROM tb; 

DROP TABLE tb;

ALTER TABLE tb_temp RENAME TO tb;
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=bde35fba4f27a385ec5ae3f6557afd1e)

Comment: Won't the output be the same?

Comment: I think maybe it might be connected to the fact that name can be a Null value. SQL and pandas as far as I know sort them differently

Comment: @user458 the statements should work (see fiddle), but to be sure: post some sample data so that we can test it